# WPF context menu dont fade away

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I'm binding an ObservableCollection to ContextMenu ItemsSource and everything seems to work fine until I click an item from the contextmenu which takes a lot of time to complete. In that case ContextMenu is not completely removed. I've tried to sleep the thread for 2 seconds but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest execute your contextmenu action inside a `BackgroundWorker`. Like that you will avoid blocking the main `UI` and display some loading to your end user :)